# Spring Data JPA: query ManyToMany, select by count

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have 2 entities: Book and Author. Each mapped to appropriate table. Also I have third table `book_author` because these two entities have relation many-to-many. I need to select from DB all the books in which the number of authors is equal to `count`.

Book:

```
    @Entity(name = "Book")
    @Table(name = "book")
    public class Book {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int idbook;

        @NotNull
        @Size(max = 100)
        private String bookName;
        private int bookYearWriting;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,   
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,        
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
        @JoinTable(name = "author_book",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns  = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") }
        )
        private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    }
```

Author:

```
    @Entity(name = "Author")
    @Table(name = "author")
    public class Author {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int idauthor;

        @NotNull
        @Size(max = 100)
        private String authorName;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,        
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "authors")
        private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    }
```

And I want to get something like that:

```java
    @Repository
    public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Integer> {
         List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(int count, Pageable pageable);
    }
```

Please tell me how I can get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Integer> {
    @Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ")
    List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: Thanks u! How can I combine 2 queries
This

    @Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ")
    List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, Pageable pageable);

and this

    List<Book> findAllByBookYearWritingIs(int year, Pageable pageable);

Comment: You could try this one:  @Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a where b.year = ?2 group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ") 
 public  List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, int year, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Thanks u again! And i have last query where need combine 2 queries

First :
`@Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ") List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, Pageable pageable);`

And second:

`List<Book> findDistinctByBookNameContainingOrAuthors_AuthorNameContaining(String text, String textAgain, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: Try this: @Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a where b.name like  CONCAT('%',:?1,'%') or a. name like  CONCAT('%',:?2,'%')  group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ") List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, String bookName, String authorName, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Sorry my fault, typed from smartphone, lets try: @Query("select b from Book b left join b.authors a where b.name like %?2% or a. name like %?3% group by b.id having count(b) = ?1 ") List<Book> findAllByAuthorsCountIs(long count, String bookName, String authorName, Pageable pageable);

Comment: Or just remove ':' from CONCAT version and fix parameters index for like "CONCAT('%',?2,'%') or a. name like CONCAT('%',?3,'%')"

Comment: If my answer is fine for you, could you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1):

you can use collection size in Hql query.

For example ...

from Book book left join book.authors where book.authors.size == 3

For more information please refer below link...

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

@Query("select book from Book book left join book.authors where book.authors.size == ?1")
 List findAllByAuthorsCountIs(int count, Pageable pageable);